# iOS version mismatch between XCode and iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode9-beta

When I specify a version for my app in XCode 9b6 under `Target->Identity->Version`, a slightly different version shows up in some areas of iTunes Connect.

For example, version/build 1.02/2 will show up as 1.2/2 while preparing, and my iTunes Connect "finished processing" will also say 1.2/2 but then logging in to iTC will show 1.02.

I've also noticed that the AppStore version shows up as 1.0, but I'm guessing that this is just a separate versioning system.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I could've been more clear, but it looks like Xvolks was able to infer it.

Answer (score 0):

The meaningless zero is probably lost when the version is parsed as an array of integers. That's why you may encounter this issue.

I suggest to not use zeros like in `007` since it will be parsed as `7`.